# A analytic function $f$ on domain $D$,which is zero on oPen set in $D$,is zero on $D$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

let $f$ is analytic function  on domain $D$.if $B(a,R)$ is open ball inside $D,$ such that $f=0,\forall z\in B(a,R)$. then does it imply $f $ is zero on full $D$. please explain

Comment: This follows from the identity theorem in complex analysis, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: [Yes, this is true.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_permanence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce it here as I like it very much. Consider the null set of $f$, it is closed (as $f$ is continuous) with non-empty interior as your ball is inside it and call $N$ the connected component which contains $a$ of this interior. If $N=D$, we are done, otherwise, consider any point of its boundary, develop $f$ in Taylor series around this point and see that this neighbourhood is in $N$. Then $N$ is closed and open. As $N\not= \emptyset$, we must have $N=D$ and $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: Thank you. Hope all is cristal clear and helps.

Answer (score 3):

That is a consequence of the identity theorem for analytic functions. For a proof see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem